# Determine the amount of specific numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine the number of such $8$-digits numbers that:

1. Their first digit (from the LHS) is $3$
2. They are dividable by $15$
3. Each digit in them appears only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking aloud here:

$x = 3abcdefg = 3*10^7 + abcdefg$

$3*10^7 = 30*10^6$ which is divisible by $15$ so we just need to find all $abcdefg$ where digits are different and not $3$ and divisible by $15$.  ($a$ could be $0$.)

As $3$ divides $abcdefg$ the sum must add up to a mutiple of $3$.  We have to choose $7$ digits from $0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9$ we must leave out 2 digits and the to digits must add up to a multiple of $3$.

So we can remove $(0,6)(0,9)(1,5)(1,8)(2,4)(2,7)(4,5)(4,8)(5,7)(6,9)(7,8)$ or 11  pairs.

As $5$ divides $abcdefg$ the last digit must $5$ or $0$.

If the last digit is $5$ then there are $8$ possible pairs to leave out.  If the last digit is $0$ then there are $9$ possible pairs to leave out.

We know need to know how many ways to rearrange $abcdef$.  There are $6!$ ways.  So there are $(9+8)6! =11,520$ such numbers.

Comment: I guess you missed pairs $(1,2)$ so the answer is $13680$ but still - thanks for the method.